# Sum of a strongly convex function and a function with Lipschitz continuous gradient

Tags: convex-analysis

Suppose we have a $\alpha$-strongly convex function $f(x)$; and another function $g(x)$ with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient; and $\alpha>L$.

Is it true that $g(x)+f(x)$ is $(\alpha-L)$-strongly convex?

Similarly, is it true that $g(x)-f(x)$ is $(\alpha-L)$-strongly concave?

Any good references would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note that since $g$ has an $L$-Lipschitz gradient, we have that $\frac{L}{2}x^Tx-g(x)$ is convex. (Check this by showing that the gradient of $h(x)=\frac{L}{2}x^Tx-g(x)$ is monotone, i.e. $\langle h(x)-h(y),x-y\rangle \geq 0 \  \forall x,y$). In particular, since $\nabla (-g)=-\nabla g$ which is also Lipschitz, $\frac{L}{2}x^Tx+g(x)$ is also convex. Thus
$$
f(x)+g(x)-\frac{\alpha-L}{2}x^Tx=f(x)-\frac{\alpha}{2}x^Tx+\frac{L}{2}x^Tx+g(x)
$$
is a sum of convex functions and therefore convex, so $f+g$ is indeed $\alpha-L$ strongly convex.

Similarly, we have
$$
g(x)-f(x)+\frac{\alpha-L}{2}x^Tx=-(\frac{L}{2}x^Tx-g(x)+f(x)-\frac{\alpha}{2}x^Tx)
$$
We know that $\frac{L}{2}x^Tx-g(x)+f(x)-\frac{\alpha}{2}x^Tx$ is convex as a sum of convex functions, so that $-(\frac{L}{2}x^Tx-g(x)+f(x)-\frac{\alpha}{2}x^Tx)$ is concave, and hence $g-f$ is $\alpha-L$ strongly concave.

Comment: thank you so much! I was wondering if would there be any references for the results. I have searched several books, but they seem all consider properties of one function f(x) instead of summation of two functions with some properties respectively.

Comment: I am not aware of a reference that deals explicitly with sums of convex functions. A good introduction to convex analysis can be found for instance in [these](https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/index.php?eID=dumpFile&t=f&f=128341&token=3c40ee32c6c029df85f7e552522f4a87470e3401) notes.

Comment: okay. thank you again for your kind help!